# MacBook Pro won't start up

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, display

This is a [15" 2010 model](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP582?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) that came with OS X 10.6 and now has 10.10 installed. After turning the computer on I can hear the startup chime and the power adapter indicator light lights up. The Apple logo and a progress bar appear, but after that there's only a blank white screen.

There are some pixel anomalies, what appears to be scanlines and slightly distorted colors that look like it's running in 16-bit color depth.

I have tried following the [official instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201177), i.e. reset the PRAM/NVRAM and SMC, tried booting in safe mode (same symptoms, but after that it seems to boot automatically in safe mode since the loading takes a lot longer).

Also I recently installed [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) if it might have to do with this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try booting in verbose mode by holding `command + V` while booting, and see where the computer stops. Post an image here.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard It seems to stall with [this screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnkleu2uo5mzl4i/IMG_2445.JPG?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was apparently some known issue because when I took the computer to be fixed, they simply replaced the motherboard for free.